# using two database with different attributes in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases on the same server.

I want to show single result from two different databases when user search any term!
how can we do this? I am using JSP

Comment: Well, to begin with you'll need to provide connections to both databases or else have a single view in one of them which includes data of the other DB. You really need to give some more info and what you have tried/thought of so far.

Comment: May this link help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183341/connect-multiple-tables-in-different-databases-mysql

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to connect with both databases. Let me explain..

> We have two databases DB_1 and DB_2, both has tables DB_1.Table1 and
>   DB_2.Table2.

Assuming that DB_1 has more tables to use in. Here you just need to provide `GRANT` on Table2 of DB_2 to DB_1. OR You may provide grant for all tables of DB_2 (as per you need). This is the way Oracle behave. If your DB server do not support the same just give the permissions ([GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)) to your DB_1's user to use multiple tables of different database.

and the query will look like..

```
Select t1.id, t1.name,t2.id, t2.name t2 from DB_1.Table1 t1, DB_2.Table2 t2 where...
```

And as you wrote

> *I want to show single result from two different databases when user search any term!*

your query will be..

```
Select t1.id, t1.name from DB_1.Table1 t1 where...
Union All
Select t2.id, t2.name from DB_2.Table2 t2 where...
```