# What is the best practice to have one large database with fed information from other 3 databases?

Tags: mysql, integration

The problem is that I have 3 databases with similar information in different sources, all are Mysql databases.For reasons of order and efficiency, I need to have only one database source with real-time data in which I be able to query. What is your recommendation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183341/connect-multiple-tables-in-different-databases-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can setup all the tables you need to query in your big database as copies of the data in the other 3 through replication. The linked question does not work at all if you have data on separate machines ("databases" is kind of ambiguous since it could mean schemas or machines). Personally I would go with the replication route if you are aggregating data from multiple machines. You can ready more about replication here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html

if you have multiple schemas in one machine you need to query then the answer is very simple and in the linked question above.